# ruby initialization with keyword args

Tags: ruby, constructor, initialization, keyword-argument

I'm reading the POODR book and it uses the old syntax for initialization with default values. I wanna implement the same with the new syntax.

```
class Gear
  attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :wheel
  def initialize(args)
    @chainring = args.fetch(:chainring, 40)
    @cog =  args.fetch(:cog, 10)
    @wheel = args[:wheel]
  end

  def gear_inches
    ratio * diameter
  end

  def diameter
    wheel * diameter
  end
end

Gear.new(chainring: 52, cog: 11, wheel: Wheel.new(26,1.5)).gear_inches
```

How would this look like with the new keyword args? This is my guess below, but not sure if it results the same for the wheel like above.

```
class Gear
  attr_reader :chainring, :cog, :wheel
  def initialize(chainring: 40, cog: 10, wheel:) #is this good here for wheel?
    @chainring = chainring
    @cog = cog
    @wheel = wheel #is this good here for wheel?
  end

  ......
end
```

Comment: `wheel: nil` would be equivalent

Answer (score 6):

The *literal* equivalent would be this:

```
class Gear
  def initialize(**args)
    @chainring = args.fetch(:chainring, 40)
    @cog =  args.fetch(:cog, 10)
    @wheel = args[:wheel]
  end
end
```

The original code allows arbitrary keys to be passed and just ignores the ones it doesn't need, therefore, we use the **ksplat to allow arbitrary arguments.

We could refactor that code to this:

```
class Gear
  def initialize(chainring: 40, cog: 10, **args)
    @chainring = chainring
    @cog = cog
    @wheel = args[:wheel]
  end
end
```

This reads slightly better. But it's still bad design: why allow the user to pass arbitrary keys? It's most likely to be a bug, when an unused key is passed. E.g. the user calls `Gear.new(cgo: 20)`, which is clearly a typo, but instead of getting an error, he will silently get wrong data (a `cog` value of `10`).

```
class Gear
  def initialize(chainring: 40, cog: 10, wheel: nil)
    @chainring = chainring
    @cog = cog
    @wheel = wheel
  end
end
```

This is equivalent to the *intended* behavior of the original code, I would guess. It behaves differently, in that it doesn't allow arbitrary keys to be passed, but I don't think that makes sense anyway. So, while not equivalent, it is arguably *better*.

However, there is still a problem (that also exists in the original code): it is possible to not pass `wheel`, making `wheel` end up `nil`. However, `wheel` is used unconditionally (e.g. in `diameter`), which means, it will blow up at runtime when `wheel` is `nil`. So, it is better to require `wheel` to be passed:

```
class Gear
  def initialize(chainring: 40, cog: 10, wheel:)
    @chainring = chainring
    @cog = cog
    @wheel = wheel
  end
end
```

Which is, of course, exactly what you had. This is *not* equivalent in behavior, but I would ague it *is* equivalent in *intent* and is arguably much better and more correct.

Comment: Jorg, thanks for the detailed answer! I've got 2 questions though: 1. Could you pls tell me you use `@chainring = args[:chainring]` instead of `@chainring = chainring` (question also goes for @cog and @wheel) in the last example? 2. So if I wanna make wheel optional then I can just use `wheel: nil` in the args, but if I wanna make it required then just use `wheel:` in the argument?

Answer (score 0):

Your example with keywords argument is not equivalent to the old way, because `:wheel` will be required, whereas in the old code it wasn't.

You can't use keyword args if you want the keywords to be optional.

Comment: Agis, and if I do what Stefan suggested in the comment above?